# algebraic integers linearly independent modulo P

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This problem comes from Marcus's Number Fields, Chapter 3 exercise 20. 
We have that $S \supset R$ are two rings of integers with corresponding number fields $L \supset K$, and $P$ is a prime ideal.

We say a set of elements of $S$ *independent* mod $P$ iff the corresponding elements in $S/PS$ are linearly independent over $R/P$.

For each prime $Q_i$ of $S$ lying over $P$, fix a subset $B_i \subset S$ corresponding to a basis for $S/Q_i$ over $R/P$. For each $i = 1, \dots, r$ and for each $j=1, \dots, e_1$, fix an element $\alpha_{ij} \in (Q^{j-1}_i-Q_i^j) \cap (\bigcap_{h \neq i} Q_h^{e_h})$. Prove that the $n = \sum e_if_i$ elements $\alpha_{ij}\beta_{ik}$, where $\beta_{ik} \in B_i$.

As per the book's suggestion, first we suppose there is a nontrivial linear combination such that it is zero modulo $P$, and consider it $\mod Q_i$.

Suppose that $S = \sum_{i,j,k} c_{ijk}\alpha_{ij}\beta_{ik} = 0$. By definition, $\alpha_{ij} \in Q^{j'}_{i'}$ for any $j'$ and $i \neq i'$, as well as $\alpha_{ij} \in Q^{j'}_i$ when $j > j'$. So, $S = \sum_{k} c_{i1k}\alpha_{i1}\beta_{ik} \mod Q_i$. Since we have that $\alpha_{i1} \not\in Q$, $\alpha_{i1}\beta_{ik}$ is going to linearly independent, so $\sum_k c_{i1k}\alpha_{i1}\beta_{ik} \equiv \sum_k c_{i1k}\beta_{ik} \mod Q_i$. Since the $\beta_{ik}$ are linearly independent, $c_{i1k} \equiv 0 \mod Q_i$. From here, when we consider it $\mod Q_i^2$, it appears that we have to deal with $2k$ elements that are all $\equiv 0 \mod Q_1$, so we should have a nontrivial linear dependence. This problem appears to get worse as $j$ increases.

Someone had posted this question before, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512832/exercise-20-on-number-fields-marcus-chapter-3), but I don't follow the part where the author says that by the definition of $\beta_{ik}$, that $c_{i1k} \in P$. Aside from that part, the rest of the question and answer follows. If someone could explain that last part as well as possibly give an explanation of what the basis of $S/Q_i$ looks like in comparison to $S/Q_{i'}$, where $i\neq i'$ (both over $R/P$), that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything becomes crystal clear once you know that the $Q_i$ become principal ideals in the quotient.

$L/K$ is a finite extension of number fields, $P$ is a prime ideal of $O_K$ and $k=O_K/P$. Let $$PO_L=  \prod_i Q_i^{e_i}, \qquad A= O_L/PO_L$$
Take $\pi_i \in A,\pi_i \in Q_i -Q_i^2, \not \in \cup_{j\ne i}Q_j$, from the unique factorization of ideals of $O_L$ then $(P,\pi_i)=Q_i$ thus $(\pi_i)= Q_i$ as ideals of $A$. Since they are distinct maximal ideals they are comaximal and

$$A = A / (\prod_i \pi_i^{e_i}) \cong \prod_i A/(\pi_i^{e_i}) $$ 
The isomorphism of $k$-vector spaces is 
$$A = \sum_i (\prod_{j\ne i} \pi_j^{e_j})\ \ A/(\pi_i^{e_i}) $$ 
Then take a $k$-basis of $A/(\pi_i)= O_L/Q_i$
$$A / (\pi_i) = \sum_{l=1}^{f_i} b_{i,l} k$$
$$A / (\pi_i^{e_i}) =\sum_{m=0}^{e_i-1}  \pi_i^m\sum_{l=1}^{f_i} b_{i,l} k$$
$$ A =\sum_{m=0}^{e_i-1} \sum_{l=1}^{f_i}(\prod_{j\ne i} \pi_j^{e_j}) \pi_i^m b_{i,l} k$$

Comment: What exactly is the $k$-vector space isomorphism from? Also what perspective should I view this from so that it's a bit more intuitive? Thanks!